# How can I get my location at a certain time?

Tags: android, location

I would like to know how can I get my location (longitude and latitude,
I dont need a position on the map) at a certain time and in the most accurate way. For example when a disconnection between two devices happen.

I have seen many examples with the Google API but they are more focused on tracking rather than obtaining the coordinates at a certain time.

I have read in some sites that getLastKnownLocation isn`t very accurate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use location update listener, but nothing will garante you that you will be able to get accurate location exactly when you need it. It is quite possible that the accurate location will be not available the moment you want it. That's what the `getLastKnownLocation` is made for.

Comment: But the last known location is not the same as the location at the time I need it or am I wrong?

Comment: last known location is the latest location update, the device has been able to retrieve. If your GPS is active and connected, then it will be actual location. If your GPS is disabled - it will be less accurate location.

Answer (score 0):

i make seperate class for get current location lat and long value.
used below class for location.

```
public class GPSController  implements
    LocationListener,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
```

{
    OnLocationUpdateListener onLocationUpdateListener;
    public final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

```
private FusedLocationProviderApi fusedLocationProviderApi = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi;
GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
Location mCurrentLocation;
private static long INTERVAL = 1000 * 10;
private static long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 1000 * 5;
FragmentActivity mActivity;
private boolean isLiveUpdate = false;


PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result;


/**
 * Checking permission and connect with Google Location service
 * @param activity
 */
public GPSController(FragmentActivity activity) {

    this.mActivity = activity;
    if(PermissionManager.checkPermission(mActivity,PermissionManager.ACCESS_LOCATION))
    {
        if (!isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
            CustomLogHandler.printInfolog("checking googleplayservice : ", "false");
            ((BaseActivity)mActivity).showAlertDialog(mActivity, mActivity.getString(R.string.app_name), mActivity.getString(R.string.play_service_not_found));
        } else {
            CustomLogHandler.printInfolog("checking googleplayservice : ", "true");
            createLocationRequest();
            initFuseAPI();

        }
    }
    else
    {
        PermissionManager.askForPermission(PermissionManager.ACCESS_LOCATION,mActivity);
    }

}

public void connectForLocation()
{
    createLocationRequest();
    initFuseAPI();
}

/**
 * Turn on Live update of location on given interval
 * @param value
 * @param INTERVAL
 * @param FASTEST_INTERVAL
 */
public void turnOnLiveUpdate(boolean value,long INTERVAL,long FASTEST_INTERVAL)
{
    isLiveUpdate = value;
    this.INTERVAL = INTERVAL;
    this.FASTEST_INTERVAL = FASTEST_INTERVAL;
}

/**
 * Turn off live update of location
 */
public void turnOffLiveUpdate()
{
    isLiveUpdate = false;
}

/**
 * Disconnect from Google location service
 */
public void disconnect()
{
    try {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStop fired ..............");
        googleApiClient.disconnect();
        Log.d(TAG, "isConnected ...............: " +googleApiClient.isConnected());
    }catch (Throwable throwable)
    {
        throwable.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Resume Location update service if stopped
 */
public void onResumeUpdate()
{
    try {
        if(googleApiClient != null) {
            if (googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                startLocationUpdates();
                Log.d(TAG, "Location update resumed .....................");
            }
        }
    }catch (Throwable throwable)
    {
        throwable.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public void setLocatonUpdateListener(OnLocationUpdateListener onLocationUpdateListener)
{
    this.onLocationUpdateListener  = onLocationUpdateListener;
}

/**
 * Create location update request
 */
protected void createLocationRequest() {
    try {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }catch (Throwable throwable)
    {
        throwable.printStackTrace();
    }
}


/**
 * Initialize google location service
 */
void initFuseAPI()
{
    try
    {
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mActivity)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
        Log.d(TAG, "initFuseAPI fired ..............");
        googleApiClient.connect();
    }catch (Throwable throwable)
    {
        throwable.printStackTrace();
    }
}


/**
 * Check Google location service is available or not
 * @return
 */
private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(mActivity);
    if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == status) {
        return true;
    } else {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, mActivity, 0).show();
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * called when connected with google location service
 * @param bundle
 */
@Override
public void onConnected( Bundle bundle) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onConnected - isConnected ...............: " + googleApiClient.isConnected());
    LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) mActivity.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );
    boolean statusOfGPS = manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if(statusOfGPS) {
        startLocationUpdates();
    }else
    {
        enableGpsService();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed( ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

/**
 * Location update received here
 * @param location
 */
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Firing onLocationChanged..............................................");
    mCurrentLocation = location;
    SetLocation();
}


void enableGpsService()
{
    try
    {
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
        builder.setAlwaysShow(true);
        result = LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(googleApiClient, builder.build());
        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult( LocationSettingsResult locationSettingsResult) {
                final Status status = locationSettingsResult.getStatus();
                switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                        //already connected to GPS
                        startLocationUpdates();
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by
                        // showing the user a dialog.
                        try {
                            status.startResolutionForResult(mActivity, PermissionManager.REQUEST_LOCATION);
                            startLocationUpdates();
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            // Ignore the error.
                        }
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                        //redirect user to setting screen, manually user can enble GPS
                        mActivity.startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }catch (Throwable throwable)
    {
        throwable.printStackTrace();
    }
}





/**
 * Request location update service
 */
public void startLocationUpdates()
{
    try {
        //check required even you checked it previously
        if (PermissionManager.checkPermission(mActivity, PermissionManager.ACCESS_LOCATION))
        {
            fusedLocationProviderApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
            Log.d(TAG, "Location update started ..............: ");
        } else {
            PermissionManager.askForPermission(PermissionManager.ACCESS_LOCATION, mActivity);
        }
    }catch (Throwable throwable)
    {
        throwable.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Stop location update
 */
public void stopLocationUpdates() {
    try {
        if(googleApiClient != null) {
            fusedLocationProviderApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                    googleApiClient, this);
            Log.d(TAG, "Location update stopped .......................");
        }
    }catch (Throwable throwable)
    {
        throwable.printStackTrace();
    }
}


/**
 * set location values received
 */
private void SetLocation()
{
    try {
        Log.d(TAG, "UI update initiated .............");
        if (null != mCurrentLocation) {
            onLocationUpdateListener.onLocationUpdate(mCurrentLocation);

            /**isLiveUpdate = true for Live update **/

            if (!isLiveUpdate) {
                fusedLocationProviderApi.removeLocationUpdates(googleApiClient,this);
            }
            googleApiClient.disconnect();

            //mCurrentLocation.getAccuracy()
            //mCurrentLocation.getProvider()

        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "location is null ...............");
        }
    }catch (Throwable throwable)
    {
        throwable.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Location getLocation(){
    return mCurrentLocation;
}
public static List<Address> getAddress(Double mLat, Double mLang, Context context)
{
    List<Address> addresses = null;
    try
    {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(mLat, mLang, 1);
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return  addresses;
}

/**
 * For receive location update
 */
public interface OnLocationUpdateListener {
     void onLocationUpdate(Location mCurrentLocation);
}
```

}

then used in activity class like below...

```
    private GPSController gpsController;
  @Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (gpsController != null)
        gpsController.disconnect();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (gpsController != null)
        gpsController.stopLocationUpdates();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    gpsController = new GPSController(getActivity());
    gpsController.setLocatonUpdateListener(this);
    if (gpsController != null)
        gpsController.onResumeUpdate();

}
   @Override
public void onLocationUpdate(Location mCurrentLocation) {
    CURRENT_LET = String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude());
    CURRENT_LANG = String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
    loadMoreItems();
}
```

also pl note activity class implement this below interface ..

```
implements GPSController.OnLocationUpdateListener
```

and you can remove permission code if you not required.

add also add two permission into manifest file..

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```